# Why is transport.sendMail() not getting called when I use it with React (nodemailer)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

So I'm new to node and react and I was trying to set up nodemailer. At the moment it's working fine if I don't run it with React.
I start a new project with
`npm init -y` then  `npm install nodemailer` and in a file called `index.js` I have the following:

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const handleClick = () => {
    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
        port: 2525,
        auth: {
            user: "user",
            pass: "pass"
        }
    });
    const message = {
        from: 'test@test.com', 
        to: 'to@email.com', 
        subject: 'This is very frustrating',
        text: 'I wish I knew why this is not working in React'
    };
    transport.sendMail(message, function (err, info) {
        console.log("transport.sendMail called")
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(info);
        }
    });
}
handleClick();
```

I run this with  `node index.js` and it works as expected and I can view the email in mailtrap.io (fake SMTP server I've found for testing).

However! My problem occurs when I try to do this in my React project.
I have the following (exact same handleClick() function) in Contact.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const Contact = () => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
            port: 2525,
            auth: {
                user: "user",
                pass: "pass"
            }
        });
        const message = {
            from: 'test@test.com', // Sender address
            to: 'to@email.com', // List of recipients
            subject: 'This is very frustrating', // Subject line
            text: 'I wish I knew why this is not working in React' // Plain text body
        };
        transport.sendMail(message, function (err, info) {
            console.log("transport.sendMail called")
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log(info);
            }
        });
    }
    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>CLICK</button>
    )
}
export default Contact
```

Which I am using as `<Contact/>` in my App.js file. The button displays, and the click works. But `transport.sendMail()` does not even execute (I don't see the output from `console.log("transport.sendMail called")`)

I'm not sure how to even start debugging, and I've spent quite a good while googling but I've found nothing of use so far, just examples that are doing the same as I. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

More details (that I don't think are relevant, but including just in case) about my react project

- I started the React project by using `npx create-react-app` and then I run it with `npm start`, it runs on localhost and port 3000
- I am using reactstrap
- When clicking the button in my React app I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Doypg.png) and when expanded (both) look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgqFQ.png)

Comment: nodemailer is for backend usage. You can't use it with react directly. You should create a server for it and an api that accepts the contact request. In the react side, you should send the request to your server

Comment: @Akshay Oh wow, figured it'd be something simple... Thanks a lot! I'll figure out how to do that then.

Comment: I would recommend using express to create the server, it can make it a lot easier